# socket.io/ express 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' with firefox, and 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' in chrome

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and express to make a multiuser app. It was working fine until I wanted to make it into multiple instances, one hosting the landing page, and separate ones running each node project.

### Firefox error

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3Xwg8R. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

### Chrome error

`GET http://localhost:5002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3XwwIP net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

### Server

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(), 
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public/multiplayerdrawing")));
server.listen(5002);
```

### Client

```
socket = io('http://localhost:5002')
socket.connect()

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connected");
})
```

Now for the fun part. What I've tried. Mostly from 24058157 answers.

`var io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});` nope

`io.origins('*:*')` nope

`io.set('origins', '*:*');` nope

`io.set('origins', 'http://mydomain.xyz:5002');` nope

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
        const headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin, //or the specific origin you want to give access to,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        };
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

nope

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

still no.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get('Origin') || '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Range');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.send(200);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

probably used this one wrong, but I don't understand it.

maybe it's my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name mysite.xyz  www.mysite.xyz;

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
location /multiplayerdrawing {
    rewrite ^/multiplayerdrawing/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5002/multiplayerdrawing; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting in console. could you add you full error as well .

Comment: I've added both full errors